# React Native Firebase Crashlitics : couldn't find DSO libhermes.so

Tags: react-native

I just set up Firebase Crashlitics and I see this error :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
> couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.wololofit/lib-main flags = 1] SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~DAa5QmzRi5oxpzp3KsccGQ==/com.wololofit-EEiD-rJZDFCbRjzPj4o-mQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0] SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2] SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2] Native lib dir: /data/app/~~DAa5QmzRi5oxpzp3KsccGQ==/com.wololofit-EEiD-rJZDFCbRjzPj4o-mQ==/lib/arm64 result: 0

From my research, this error is for some devices that don't support Hermes : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29528

Several solutions are often proposed :

**Solution 1.** add to `android/app/build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+'
```

**Solution 2.** add :

```
if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    qaImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    stageImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    prodImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

**Solution 3.** add :

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

These proposals date from several different periods.
Not having this crash on my phone (it is found on Crashlitics), I don't know which solution to choose.

Comment: Hi Gaylord, I am having the same issue. Did you able to come up with a solution? I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1.**

I don't think this one is mandatory if you're using react-native `v0.64.2` or above since it includes `soloader` already

**Option 2.**

This is a needed if you are using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#android-1) or in general using using custom `buildTypes` like for example:

```
    buildTypes {
      debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
      }
      // Added
      staging { 
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']        
      }
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
      }
}
```

In this sample, we added `staging` build type which is not there by default. In this case, we need to include Hermes in the staging build type by adding it like so:

```
if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    stagingImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar") // Added
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

as well as add the following lines to exclude debugger from staging build

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    
    devDisabledInStaging: true, // Added
    bundleInStaging: true, // Added
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I could always fix this wierd issue by adding *solution1* which is `implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+'`

But recently it didn't help and this workaround fixed it (*react-native-0.63.4*)

in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android: {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    defaultConfig {
       ...
    }
    ...

}
```